# Making page content not fixed

Tags: html, css

I have http://jsfiddle.net/EN8CX/

What I want to do first is set the default page to have the footer at the bottom. Is there a better way than modifying the content's height?

```
#content {
min-height:200px;}
```

I'm asking this because I can't set a fixed height for the content. Later on I will add a search function which might have to display more results than the page, so I'll need a scroll bar. That will push the footer down, of course. How can I do it?

Comment: As you said you will be using scroll bar later for search results, then i don't think you will require to set min-height of the box. Just provide height and scroll bar css. Because in any case you are not increasing the height of the div for search results, you are providinh scroll bar.

Comment: But the website looks too small, I want it to initially cover the whole page, not sit at the top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself was in this same predicament and took me a while to figure this out. But I think I got it!  So you would have to modify your HTML a little bit.  You need to take out the footer and place it in the same level as the container. So it'll look something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

In the CSS, make the "container" with the minimum height of the whole viewport using "vh" units.  Then take the footer height and use it to pad the bottom of the content.  Take the footer and reverse the margin upward to make it peak through using again the height of the footer:

```
#container {
  ...
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  ...
  padding-bottom: 70px; // if footer height = 70px;
} 

#footer {
  ...
  margin-top: -70px;
}
```

I have a fiddle running here: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8CX/5/ .  I also added a button to grow the content so you can see the footer get pushed down.

Comment: But, I should add as much padding as it should occupy the page? Isn't there another more dynamic way?

Comment: The only "non" dynamic piece in this will be the height of the footer.  The padding of the content in my example above has nothing to do with the space between the page, it's only a piece to make sure the footer never overlaps the content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use below code for this purpose.

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:auto">
</div>
```

Until you search results are not crossing 100px height of div (even though you have empty search result), div will be height of 100px, but as your result grows bigger (expands) div will show scroll bar for them.